# Xcode quick help not working with Swift

Tags: xcode, documentation

I have Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b) and I'm trying to use the documentation.  When I hold options and click a string class or something...the little help pop-up appears but then when I click "String" nothing happens... How do I fix this? Is it hiding? I looked at the other windows and I couldn't find it. This is for Swift btw